# How to store the output of a terminal command in a text files but prepend an additional line

Tags: linux, command-line, bash

I want to run this command in a folder to generate the audio checksum for all FLAC files, like so:

```
$ metaflac --show-md5sum *.flac > flacsum.txt
```

It generated a `flacsum.txt` file that looks like so:

```
01 - First Track.flac:0d10049cfb5e675e2adff811d6f918a3
02 - Second Track.flac:3adab834d1508e4cd3a72551eb5f1ae4
03 - Third Track.flac:747b61a2004d1b278591a6f3fe27b1bd
```

That's fine, however I would like to do the same thing but prepend a title in the "flacsum.txt" file plus a blank new line below it, before the output goes into the file, like so:

```
MD5 hashes generated using metaflac --show-md5sum

01 - First Track.flac:0d10049cfb5e675e2adff811d6f918a3
02 - Second Track.flac:3adab834d1508e4cd3a72551eb5f1ae4
03 - Third Track.flac:747b61a2004d1b278591a6f3fe27b1bd
```

Is a way to accomplish that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can redirect output of many commands, each on its own:

```
echo "MD5 hashes generated using metaflac --show-md5sum" > flacsum.txt
echo >> flacsum.txt
metaflac --show-md5sum *.flac >> flacsum.txt
```

Note all but the first command use the `>>` operator which appends to the file.

Or better group the commands and redirect output from the whole group:

```
{ echo "MD5 hashes generated using metaflac --show-md5sum"
echo
metaflac --show-md5sum *.flac
} > flacsum.txt
```

Comment: Ninja'd so upvoted